# what is the meaning %*s in sscanf function

Tags: c, scanf

New to C programming , feel free to correct me.

```
int main()
{
    char sent[]="mugiwara is 18 years old";
    char str[20];
    int i;
    sscanf(sent,"%s%*s%d",str,&i);
    printf("\n%s->%d",str,i);

    return 0;
}
```

In the above c program what in the world `%*s` is doing in the `sscanf` statement ? I tried removing it and then a garbage value comes up when i try to run the program , kindly explain.

Comment: Have you considered reading the documentation of the `sscanf()` function?

Comment: `"%*s"` 1) Skip leading white-space then 2) skip non-whitespace.

Comment: A good [`scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) might help you.

Comment: On an unrelated note, why do you place the newline *first* when printing output? If you run the program from a command-line then the output and the command-line prompt would be on the same line, back-to-back to each other. Also, output to `stdout` (which `printf` uses) is by default *line buffered*, meaning that output is flushed from the internal buffers when you print a newline. Printing a newline when nothing is buffered makes no sense, while printing a newline after the output will actually cause the output to be printed.

Comment: And adding to [@JohnBollinger's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34337278/what-is-the-meaning-s-in-sscanf-function#comment56415882_34337278) the `sscanf()` documentation will let you know that as it is, there is a problem with your code, because it might invoke undefined behavior at the `printf()` line.

Comment: @iharob: ok, deleted.

Answer (score 8):

`%*s` in `sscanf` will read the data from the stream and then discard it . It will not store that read data into any variable ,and therefore , does not require to pass any argument for that sepcifier in`sscanf`.

[For reference - `sscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)

> (optional) assignment-suppressing character *. If this option is present, the function does not assign the result of the conversion to any receiving argument.

Answer (score 0):

> "I tried removing it and then a garbage value comes up when i try to run the program."

C provides return values from many functions that good code uses to prevent such problems.  `sscanf()` returns the count of successfully saved values (or EOF).  If this is not 2, then `i` was not successfully scanned.

```
// sscanf(sent,"%s%*s%d",str,&i);
if (sscanf(sent,"%s%*s%d",str,&i) == 2) {
  printf("\n%s->%d",str,i);
} else {
  printf("\nFailed to scan <%s>\n",sent);

}
```

`"%s"` directs `sscanf()` to 1) consume and not save white-space.  2) Consume and save non-white- space characters until 3) white-space detected, EOF or input error.

`"%*s"` does the same except no data is saved in step 2.  Also: success or failure of this directive does not contribute to the return value.